# A sitemap index needs to be in the website root, but do the referenced sub-sitemaps also need to be in the root?

Tags: sitemap, xml

My Website have to split on three Sections , **Windows 10**, **Windows 8** and **Windows 7** .Now build Three articles which explain how install Virtual Box on **Windows 10**, **Windows 8** and **Windows 7** , therefore build a sitemap for every sections;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
<url>
 <loc>http://htmlkurss.xyz/windows10.php</loc>
 <news:news>
   <news:publication>
    <news:name>htmlkurss</news:name>
    <news:language>de</news:language>
   </news:publication>
   <news:genres/>
   <news:publication_date>2019-03-28</news:publication_date>
   <news:title>Wie instaliert Virtual Box in Windows 10 </news:title>
   <news:keywords>Virtual Box, installation, Windows 10</news:keywords>
  </news:news>
 </url>
</urlset>
```

Name File , **sitemap_windows10.xml** . Then for **Windows 8** and **Windows 7**. My Idea is to build a sitemap structure as [here](https://blog.spotibo.com/sitemap-guide/#create-a-structure-for-sitemaps-with-a-sitemap-index) say .

When the sitemaps_index.xml should to be on Root of the site, where should to be the Sitemaps referenced (**sitemap_windows10.xml**)?

Comment: I removed the [Tag:SEO] tag from your question.  Sitemaps have very little to do with getting your site indexed and ranked.  It usually happens without a sitemap.  Adding a sitemap gives you additional data in Google Search Console, but doesn't usually help indexing or rankings.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Comment: Unless you have 50,000 pages on you site, there is no need to create separate sitemaps for different sections.   You can put all your URLs for all your sections into a single XML sitemap as long as there aren't too many total for the file size.

Comment: It appears that the example you gave shouldn't have the `<news:news>` section in it.  It isn't a news article.  That section is only needed if you have news articles that you want to have included in Google News.

Comment: @ Stephen Ostermille , thanks for your answer and correction  ! , when can't write <news:news> , how write my  sitemap_windows10.xml ?

Comment: `<url><loc>http://htmlkurss.xyz/windows10.php</loc></url>` without the `news` section would be fine. There are a [few other fields](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) such as `lastmod`, `changefreq`, and `priority` that can be included, but you don't need to.  Google ignores those additional fields.

Comment: you mean write only a sitemap index with links , as these example.. http://edition.cnn.com/sitemaps/sitemap-index.xml , or it is better without sitemap index , only a sitemap with links ?

Comment: You should only include the URL field and nothing else, similar to that CNN sitemap.  However, it isn't a sitemap index then, it is a regular sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen Ostermiller give me the solution .I have a few mistake to do....

Because my Website is not a News Site (Newspaper) , I can't to write `<news:news>` .
How now to write my sitemap .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
    <url><loc>http://htmlkurss.xyz/windows10.php</loc></url>
</urlset>
```

and every time which write a new article , add the link to these File .The File stay on Root of the site .Without to write a sitemap index .